# When do JSON Web Tokens get encoded and decoded?

Tags: authentication, encoding, oauth, oauth-2.0, jwt

I've heard all good things about the JWT (JSON Web Tokens) - but am a bit fuzzy on the encoding and decoding portion. When exactly does this encoding/decoding take place, and what kind of advantages does it provide and what are some of its limitations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**encoding**

The header and payload of the JWT is base64url encoded by the issuer before signing because signature is performed on encoded content. The binary signature is also encoded in base64

**Decoding**

The receiver decodes the base64 signature and verifies it with the secret/public key. After this decodes the token

Encoding allows to get a compact token that can be attached easily to http requests using a restricted set of characters. Base64 url encoding adds an.extra size about 33%

Comment: Could you show me where I can learn a bit more about signing and how it works?

Comment: I do not know of any especially recommendable links, but you could start searching for `cryptography`, which are the mathematics behind hashing, signature and encryption processes, `pki` that describes public key cryptography with asymmetric keys, and `digital signature formats` to search for electronic signature packaging formats such as CMS, XMLDsig or PADES